# Using Array Prototype Slice Call

Tags: javascript

The following piece of code (from msdn) is a simple implementation of the 'bind' function:

```
/* Approximation of `Function.prototype.bind` from ES5 (without error checking) */
Function.prototype.bind = function(thisArg) {
  var fn = this, args = *Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)*;
  return function() {
     return fn.apply(thisArg, args.concat(*Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)*));
  };
 };
```

Can anyone explain the first call to Array.prototype.slice.call ? I understand that arguments is not an array and one needs to turn it into an array before using slice and concat. I don't understand the first call - aren't we losing the first element when calling

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

The zeroth element of `arguments` is `thisArg`, which is why it is getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs about [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), the first argument (`arguments[0]`) is the custom `this` value to be used as the value of `this` within the the function returned by `bind` (the "bound function").

What follows (`arguments[1]` - `arguments[n]`) are arguments that are *to be prepended* when calling the bound function, in addition to the arguments that are provided to when called.

What the first `Array.prototype.slice.call` does is to slice the arguments passed to `bind` call and get the arguments to be prepended starting from the second argument passed, leaving behind the first argument which would be our `this`.

For example

```
var newFN = someFunction.bind(myNewThis,foo,bar,baz);
```

The first `Array.prototype.slice.call` takes `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

In the returned function, `foo`, `bar` and `baz` get prepended to the arguments provided when calling the bound function:

```
//fn - original function
//args - extracted arguments foo, bar and baz
//thisArg - the provided `this` value, myNewThis

//this code basically:
// - calls the original function (fn) 
// - provides a custom `this` value (thisArg)
// - provides arguments that comprise the extracted arguments + the passed arguments
fn.apply(thisArg, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
```

So when you use the new "bound" function, you get a custom `this` value, as well as a "preset", prepended arguments list:

```
newFN('ban','bam'); //arguments === ['foo','bar','baz','ban','bam'];
```

Comment: OK that clarifies a bit . However why the need to concat args with arguments in fn.apply ? I would think that once we created our args variable we would just pass it to apply.